# while loop not behaving as expected?

Tags: java

```
package uk.ac.sheffield.aca14js;

public class Chess {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        Board chessBoard = new Board();
        Pieces white = new Pieces(chessBoard,1);
        Pieces black = new Pieces(chessBoard,0);
        Display board = new TextDisplay();
        Player one,two = null;
        one = new HumanPlayer("John",white,chessBoard,two);
        two = new HumanPlayer("opponent",black,chessBoard,one);
        one.setOpponent(two);

        int x = 0;


        while (x == 0){
            board.showPiecesOnBoard(chessBoard.getData());
            while (one.makeMove() != true){
                System.out.println("Choose a valid move");
                board.showPiecesOnBoard(chessBoard.getData());          
                one.makeMove();         
            }   
            board.showPiecesOnBoard(chessBoard.getData());  
            while (two.makeMove() != true){
                System.out.println("Choose a valid move");
                board.showPiecesOnBoard(chessBoard.getData());          
                two.makeMove();         
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is for the player to select a move and if it is valid make the move and if not retake the move.

If every move selected is valid the game goes fine with players alternating there turns.

If one player makes an invalid move the game then stays on there turn even if they make a valid move after until they  make another invalid move.

Is there something wrong with my while loops? (the infinite loop is just for testing at the moment).

Comment: I would change the `if(x == 0)` that is always true, simply to `if(true)`

Comment: Same is true for the while loops... you can simplify them to `while(!one.makeMove())`

Comment: It probably is either `while (!one.madeMove())` (with a "d") or as @Eran said (remove the second `one.makeMove()`). Depends on the `HumanPlayer` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many calls to `makeMove()` :

```
        while (one.makeMove() != true){
            System.out.println("Choose a valid move");
            board.showPiecesOnBoard(chessBoard.getData());          
            one.makeMove(); // remove this     
        }   
        board.showPiecesOnBoard(chessBoard.getData());  
        while (two.makeMove() != true){
            System.out.println("Choose a valid move");
            board.showPiecesOnBoard(chessBoard.getData());          
            two.makeMove(); // remove this
        }
```

Since you are already calling `makeMove()` in the loop's condition, there's no need to call it again in the loop's body.

Comment: How do you know? We have no idea what `makeMove` does since it's not posted with the code ...

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I can't be sure, but based on the behavior the OP describes, it's very likely.